# Modern equivalent to Landau & Lifshitz lectures in theoretical physics

Tags: resource-recommendations, soft-question, education

Is there a modern equivalent to the Landau  & Lifshitz lecture series in theoretical physics?
I know the 10 volume series by Landau & Lifshitz is still relevant and very useful. But is there a more modern version that serves a similar purpose in providing the so called theoretical minimum for theoreticians?

Comment: There is the German equivalent of LL, written in the 1980s, the Greiner series (all books translated from DE to EN). These are enough to serve as university physics eduation material.

Comment: Also, does it cover some of the more modern developments? I believe with the advent of more powerful personal computers, many scalable numerical methods have been developed and are an essential part of basic graduate-level education in physics.

Comment: Spoon feeding is not my cup of tea. Go on Amazon, search by "Greiner Quantum Mechanics", then discover the whole series. Numerical methods have their own books. Greiner, as L&L only provide the standard theory.

Comment: This question (v3) seems _too broad_ for a useful res. recom. q.

Comment: Hmmm...   G&M is known for index-happy misconceptions, quite orthogonal to the spirit of L&L...  but I'd be reluctant to get into proper deconstruction here...

Comment: Do you mean an entire set of books by the same authors ?  As it stands it's pretty much "books for a course on theoretical physics" and we could list those ad nauseam (and some L&L titles would easily make such a list).

Comment: The aim to know if there is a series like L&L or if nor could we put together a recommendation list on the lines in which the course was given by L&L. Something that would survey advanced graduate-level topics in theoretical physics serving as a primer. Maybe something like an essential 'theoretical minimum' for a qualifier.

Comment: The best I can think of is David Tong's lecture notes. They're not a book series, but they do cover everything up to Master's level in a modern way.

Comment: Then someone, who knows him please request him to convert that to a complete book series! X)

Comment: They're already so polished that they almost _are_ books! They even come with problems.

Comment: On a more serious note David tong's lectures, are missing some of the more important parts of in CMP. Also, the E&M part is limited up to basic discussion. Electrodynamics is also not covered and there are no lecture notes on classical field theory. Honestly, in no way can they be compared to L&L.